# Rewriting rails url from port 3000?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mod-rewrite, cgi, fastcgi

i have an applicaiton that runs at actionengineers.com:3000. How do i reqwite the application to a subdomain or directory (actionengineers.com/myapp) without disturbing the main site of course. i tried to use .htaccess file but i allways get eror 404. here is the code in the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.deep.actionengeneers.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1\:3000%{REQUEST_URI}" [P,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.deep.actionengeneers.com
RewriteRule ^ http://127.0.0.1:3000%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]
```

Now all requests to *www.deep.actionengeneers.com* are getting passed through to *127.0.0.1:3000* via proxy.